# Is Brahman the source of ALL scripture?

Tags: brahman, source, non-hindu

One poster cites Sankaracharya as

"Brahman is the source, i.e. the cause of the great body of Scripture, consisting of the Ṛg-veda and other branches"

Is Brahman the source of all scripture, including non-Hindu ones?

Comment: Both Bible and Quran are said to be from God. But other scriptures could be from devatas, asuras, etc. Yaksha prashna of the Mahabharata is authored by a Yaksha. Indra has his own revelations, etc.

Comment: Are you specifically asking the question for non-Hindu texts? Because questions for Hindu text and non-Hindu text should be separate.

Comment: Brahman is the source of sruti, the vedas. Other scriptures are smriti.

Comment: Is all scripture apart from Sruti man-made? @swami vishwananda